# Clifford product of force and distance

Tags: clifford-algebras

$fd = force*distance$

$fd = (f_1\mathbf{e_1} + f_2\mathbf{e_2})(d_1\mathbf{e_1} + d_2\mathbf{e_2})$

$fd = f_1d_1\mathbf{e_1}\mathbf{e_1} + f_2d_2\mathbf{e_2}\mathbf{e_2} + f_1d_2\mathbf{e_1}\mathbf{e_2} + f_2d_1\mathbf{e_2}\mathbf{e_1}$

$fd = f_1d_1\mathbf{e_1}\mathbf{e_1} + f_2d_2\mathbf{e_2}\mathbf{e_2} + f_1d_2\mathbf{e_1}\mathbf{e_2} - f_2d_1\mathbf{e_1}\mathbf{e_2}$

$fd = f_1d_1\mathbf{e_1}\mathbf{e_1} + f_2d_2\mathbf{e_2}\mathbf{e_2} + (f_1d_2 - f_2d_1)\mathbf{e_1}\mathbf{e_2}$

$fd = Scalar + Bivector?$

The scalar is just the energy but what is the bivector?

Comment: Are you considering dot or cross product?

Comment: Neither. Its the Clifford product. Also call geometric product

Comment: Sorry I thought you were asking a uestion about physics!

Comment: I think you were a bit hasty in deleting your answer. It may not have been the full answer but there was good information there.

Comment: It is physics..

Comment: ok then I undelete!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in physics classical mechanics context

- for dot product $f\cdot d=f_1d_1+f_2d_2$ is the definition of **work**
- for cross product $f\times d=(f_1d_2-f_2d_1)\mathbf{e_3}$ is the definition of **torque**

Comment: Cross product is only defined for three dimensions. And all others it is called The Wedge product. And it results in a bivector

Comment: @R.Emery Indeed I think thet this question is out of my knowledge, are you sure it can be useful for your OP?

Comment: Yes. I think its probable torque

Comment: @R.Emery Of course that's the classical interpretation for ordinary algebra, but this kind of extension is beyond my knowledge!

Comment: I don't think it's as far beyond your knowledge as you think it is. It's actually quite simple

Comment: The $d$ in these two quantities is not the same. Work uses a displacement vector, while torque uses a position vector. Work is done along a path, while torque is exerted at a point relative to another point (the origin).