# Combining the Laws of classical mechanics into a single equation using multi vectors

Tags: clifford-algebras

Maxwell's laws can be combined into a single equation using multi vectors. What about the Laws of classical mechanics? Can they be combined into a single equation?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Geometric_algebra_formulations

Conservation of energy and conservation of momentum sound very much like the scalar and vector parts of a multivector equation

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2697186/clifford-product-of-force-and-distance

Comment: In relativity theory energy and momentum are actually combined into a 4-vector.